# Is it possible to speed up this code by eliminating "For" loop?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, map

I am finding how to speed up a code.
The code and general equation are as below.

```
tablenumber = 3;     
listnumber = 10;
t1 = Table[Table[RandomInteger[10], {listnumber}], tablenumber];   (* Data to be analyzed. *)
t2 = Table[ReverseSort[Array[Array[0.0 &, #] &, {Length[t1[[1]]] - 1}]], tablenumber];   (* Empty list for interim result. *)
t3 = Table[Table[0.0, {Length[t1[[1]]] - 1}], tablenumber];   (* Empty list for result. *)

For[i = 1, i <= tablenumber, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= Length[t2[[i]]], j++,
   t2[[i, j]] = Map[(t1[[i, # + j]] - t1[[i, #]]) &, Range[Length[t1[[1]]] - j]];
   t3[[i, j]] = Sqrt[Total[Map[t2[[i, j, #]]^2 &, Range[Length[t2[[i, j]]]]]]/Length[t2[[i, j]]]]
   ];
 ]
```

[image]

*x*_*n* corresponds to `t1[[i]]`.
*G*(*md*) corresponds to `t3[[i]]`.

In the actual use, I assume tablenumber=100 and listnumber=1,000,000.
In that case, the code is heavily time-consuming.

I suppose that the use of "For" is the cause of time consuming.
However, I do not have an idea how to eliminate "For" from this code.

(**"Map" with #** is already used in the `t2[[i, j]] = Map[(t1[[i, # + j]] - t1[[i, #]]) &, Range[Length[t1[[1]]] - j]];`. That's why I am using **"For" with i and j** in this equation.)

Best regards.

---

### Additive question

Owing to the code by ciao, the calculation becomes much faster.
(`t3m = Table[Sqrt[Plus @@ ((#[[-xx ;;]] - #[[1 ;; xx]])^2)]/Sqrt[xx],{xx, listnumber - 1, 1, -1}] & /@ t1;`)

However, when applying `tablenumber` = `10` and `listnumber` = `1,000,000`, the estimated calculation time is about 193 hours (7E-07x^2-0.0035x [second], where x is listnumber). It is still time consuming.

Here, I have checked the CPU-processing of my computer (i7-8700K having 6core/12thread and 64GB-RAM).
While the calculation, only one thread became 100%-processing and the others were less than 15%.

By the way, in some cases, `ParallelMap` is faster than `Map`. While processing, `ParallelMap` uses all core/thread.

The additive question is that

"Is it possible to use all core/thread in the calculation for speed up?"

or "Is it possible to parallelize the calculation for speed up?".

Best regards.

Comment: Do you need to have access to the interim result?

Comment: >> CA Trevillian,  Thank you for checking the code. The interim result is not necessary. Just to make me easy to write and understand the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sum can be split into

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N-m} (x_{n+ m } - x_{n})^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{N-m} x_{n+ m }^2 - 2 \sum_{n=1}^{N-m} x_{n+ m } x_{n} + \sum_{n=1}^{N-m} x_{n}^2.$$

If I got it correctly, then OP wants to do all the summations for $m=1,\dotsc, N-1$ and that $N$ is rather larger. So it might be worthwhile to consider other strategies than direct computations.

For example, the two outer sums above are easy to compute. One computes once a list of accumulates of the quadratic terms in $\Theta(N)$ time:

$$X_1 := x_1^2, \quad X_{i+1} := X_i+ x_{i+1}^2.$$

Then the first sum is just $\sum_{n=1}^{N-m} x_{n+ m }^2 = \sum_{n=m+1}^{N} x_{n}^2 = X_{N} - X_{m}$ and the third is $\sum_{n=1}^{N-m} x_{n}^2 = X_{N-m}$. So the outer sums for all $m$ together can be computed in $\Theta(N)$ time instead of $\Theta(N^2)$.

This would not help much if we would not be able to get a hold on the sums $y_m := \sum_{n=1}^{N-m} x_{n+ m } x_{n}$. However, these are of convolutionary nature. So something tells me that one should be able to speed this up by a clever application of the fast Fourier transform (or related methods just as `ListConvolve` or `ListCorrelate`), but I just cannot put the finger on it...

### Addendum:

Finally I figured out how to use `ListCorrelate`. All what was needed was a suitable padding.

```
NN = 1000;
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, NN];
ytrue = Table[Sum[x[[m + n]] x[[n]], {n, 1, NN - m}], {m, 1, NN - 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
yfaster = Table[x[[j ;;]].x[[;; -j]], {j, 2, NN}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
yfastest = Rest@ListCorrelate[x, x, {1, 1}, ConstantArray[0., NN]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[ytrue - yfaster]]/Max[Abs[ytrue]]
Max[Abs[ytrue - yfastest]]/Max[Abs[ytrue]]
```

> 0.828028
>
> 0.002384
>
> 0.00013
>
> 1.15899*10^-15
>
> 1.21694*10^-15

### Putting things together

The function `ftrue` does what you want to a single vector `x` in the straight-forward implementation.

```
ftrue = x \[Function] With[{NN = Length[x]},
    Table[
     1/(NN - m) Sum[(x[[n + m]] - x[[n]])^2, {n, 1, NN - m}],
     {m, 1, NN - 1}
     ]
    ];
```

Now the tuned version:

```
ffast = x \[Function] With[{X = Accumulate[x^2], NN = Length[x]},
   Plus[
     Subtract[Rest@Reverse[X] + X[[-1]], Most[X]],
     Rest@ListCorrelate[-2. x, x, {1, 1}, ConstantArray[0., NN]]
     ]/Range[NN - 1, 1, -1]
   ]
```

Accuracy and performance comparison:

```
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000];
trueresult = ftrue[x]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
fastresult = ffast[x]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[trueresult - fastresult]]/Max[Abs[trueresult]]
```

> 1.04949
>
> 0.002378
>
> 1.36369*10^-14

Superb. Since `ffast` has nearly linear scaling (thanks to the built-in FFT), we can do the job for a list of one million numbers in two and a quarter seconds:

```
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000000];
fastresult = ffast[x]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 2.2488

That means that we can do the whole job in about four minutes

```
tablenumber = 100;
listnumber = 1000000;
t1 = N@RandomInteger[10, {tablenumber, listnumber}];
t3 = Sqrt@Map[ffast, t1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 233.429

Comment: Yep - I've been scratching my head around the latter paragraph today. Problem is, it's like a "sliding" of convolutions, and I too am shooting blanks as to how (or if) this can be done cleverly. +1

Comment: Thank you for the perspective for the fundamental solution. I'll try to find the fast calculation method of the convolutionary nature.

Comment: Am I missing something here? This gives a wildly different result from OP...

Comment: @ciao Not you, but _I_ was missing something: The square root at the end. =)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher - brilliant. I'd +1 again if I could.

Comment: @ciao Thanks! =D

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher - bounty added for you, will award when timer on it runs its course.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  Thank you very much. Your strategy and the code are really smart and fast.

Comment: Thank you, you're welcome.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Henrik, what do you think of something like this 
 `yalu[m_] := Module[{test},
  
  test = Times @@@ Transpose[ {RotateLeft[x, m], x}];
  Total[test[[1 ;; NN- m]]]
  
  ]
`

Comment: @Alucard If you run `yalu[m]` for `m` from `m` to `NN-1` then this has quadratic complexity: It requires about `NN^2` flops. The point of `ListCorrelate` is that it applies FFT (which has runtime about `3 NN Log[3 NN]`), multiplies in the Fourier domain (`3 NN` flops`) and apllies inverse FFT  (again `3 NN Log[3 NN]` flops). So this is requires only about `6 NN Log[3 NN]` flops -- so it will be significantly faster already for quite moderate `NN`.

Comment: @Alucard Another issue with `yalu` is that `RotateLeft` and `Transpose` are memory bound. `yalu2[m_] := x[[m + 1 ;;]].x[[;; NN - m]]` would do already a lot better; that comes from the fact that modern CPUs have some extra circuits for dot-products (in double precision). Still it is `NN^2` complexity.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher thanks

Answer (score 7):

Given your `t1`, this will exactly reproduce `t3` without needing any of the other code in your OP:

```
t3m = Table[Sqrt[Plus @@ ((#[[-xx ;;]] - #[[1 ;; xx]])^2)]/Sqrt[xx], 
            {xx, listnumber - 1, 1, -1}] & /@ t1;
```

For `tablenumber` and `listnumber` of `10` and `500` respectively, your code takes about 3 minutes on my laptop, the above takes about a quarter of a second. As the  values are increased, this advantage grows.

That said, you're still talking about a lot of work for the desired numbers you mention in the OP.

What exactly is the purpose / end result of this calculation - there is probably a much more direct way of arriving at the result, but few will want to decode the meaning from the code.

Assuming you don't actually need arbitrary precision results, using:

```
cl = Compile[{{l, _Integer, 1}}, Module[{z, ll = Length@l},
    z = ConstantArray[0., ll - 1];
    For[k = 1, k < ll, k++,
     z[[k]] = 
      Sqrt[Total[(l[[k + 1 ;; ll]] - l[[;; -(k + 1)]])^2]]/
       Sqrt[ll - k]];
    z], CompilationTarget -> "WVM", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

And then using it as:

```
result=ParallelMap[cl, t1]
```

should significantly speed things. You can try `"C"` instead of `"WVM"` as the compilation target if you have the needed ancillaries, though I doubt the simple construct will net much difference between the two.

Further optimizations give us:

```
cl2 = Compile[{{l, _Integer, 1}}, Module[{z, ll, k},
    ll = Length@l;
    z = ConstantArray[0., ll - 1];
    For[k = 1, k < ll, k++,
     z[[k]] = 
      Sqrt[Plus @@ ((l[[k + 1 ;; ll]] - l[[;; -(k + 1)]])^2)]/
       Sqrt[ll - k]];
    z], CompilationTarget -> "C"(*"WVM"*), RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];
```

By tweaking the code to avoid callbacks to the kernel in the heavy parts, compiling to C brings significant speedup.

This is used same as above, e.g.:

```
result=ParallelMap[cl2,t1];
```

This routine took ~1 hour (with other work going on simultaneously) on my laptop for a one million element list, so your 100 x 1000000 task over 4 parallel kernels should take ~1 day to finish, dependent o/c on your CPU.

I'll ponder further, but I don't think there's much more in this: You are, after all, calculating a result that has about half a trillion sums at its leaves...

Comment: Thank you very much! It works much faster than my code. However, it seems that the code is still time consuming in the view point of the large `listnumber` such as 1,000,000. I added additve question above. Could you check that?

Comment: The aim of this calculation is actually for the equation that is used in the field of roughness analysis. It is called height-height correlation function. If possible, please check the references such as [Lechenault et al. PRL 104, 025502 (2010)].

Comment: @GaAs see update

Comment: I tried `cl` and `cl2` applying to a one million element list. At least, the `cl` didn't finish in 5 hours. The `cl2` finished only ~1 hour as your case! Thank you very much for the effort you have dedicated and improving my code.