# How to use ListCorrelate

Tags: functions

In the previous question, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216251/51448, I asked how to speed up a code of an equation.

The answer (the function "ffast" in the above link) is using `ListCorrelate` and very fast.

Now, I want to convert an equation (that would be similar to "ffast") to mathematica code, but I could not get it.

The equation, A(m), is here:

[image]

where s_i and t_i are list having n points, and 1<=m<=n-1.
For example,

```
n=1000000;
s=RandomReal[{-1,1},n];
t=RandomReal[{-1,1},n];
```

n is a large number, thus I need fast code.

Is it possible to write a fast code like as "ffast"?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards.

> Here is the additional equation

[image]

Comment: By the way, you might find it helpful to try using `Compile` to speed your code up, especially with these kinds of operations! (I don’t think `ListCorrelate` compiles, but the basic operations like `Dot` and `Part` should, I think. You can check by using `CompilePrint` and making sure there are no `MainEvaluate`s.)

Comment: (You might (separately) also find it helpful to use parallelism, though it can be tricky.)

Comment: >thorimur Thank you for the useful information, especially CompilePrint. That's new to me. But, is Compile applicable to the "Dot and Part"? The code I wrote is below (n, la, lb are the same) and got errors: **func = Compile[{{m,_Integer}}, (la[[m + 1 ;;]] - la[[;; n - m]]).(lb[[m + 1 ;;]] - lb[[;; n - m]])/(n - m)]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you write is not a correlation. But you may calculate this e.g. by using `Part` and `Dot`. Here is a small example:

```
n = 5;
la = Array[Subscript[a, #] &, n];
lb = Array[Subscript[b, #] &, n];
fun[m_] := (la[[m + 1 ;;]] - la[[;; n - m]]).(lb[[m + 1 ;;]] - 
     lb[[;; n - m]])/(n - m)

fun[2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!
It may be difficult to apply the large n (e.g. 1,000,000), but it works well.
The question I posted at the beginning lacked explanation and was not clear, but I looked at the expanded equation ("additional equation") and imagined that this was related to ListCorrelation.

Comment: When **n=1000000 and la = Array[Subscript[a, #] &, n];** is used, it takes very long time.
However, when **la = Table[RandomReal[], {1000000}];** is used, it is done immediately (0.0001 s, in my case).
I don't know why, but the code works practically!

Comment: It looks like symbolic arrays are not as efficiently implemented like numeric arrays. This makes sense as symbolic arrays are often much smaller than numeric ones.